# Array vs ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to become more acquainted with ArrayList. I was wondering how to do the equivalent operations with an Array List as compared to tan array.

```
heap[hole]=heap[child];

heap[hole]=temp;

heap[hole]=heap[hole/2];
```

Comment: yeah, sorry should have specified

Comment: New to the site, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList heapList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(heap));
heapList.set(hole, heapList.get(child));

heapList.set(hole, temp);

heapList.set(hole, heapList.get(hole/2);
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you.  I figured there had to be a better way then using a bunch of variables and swapping things in and out.

Comment: @user3003584 - Why would you expect that?  That's how you would do it with an array.

Answer (score 3):

The directly equivalent operations between Java arrays and lists are:

- `list.get(i)` is equivalent to the expression `array[i]`
- `list.set(i, v)` is equivalent to the statement `array[i] = v;`
- `list.size()` is equivalent to the expression `array.length`

There is also an equivalence between the "for each" iteration of arrays and lists.

These equivalences apply for all kinds of `List` ... not just `ArrayList`.  However for some `List` implementations, the positional `set` and `get` methods are expensive.

---

Having said that, wrapping an array as a list (using `Arrays.asList`) is something you would only do if you needed to generalize over arrays and lists.  And it won't work for arrays of primitive types.  If what your is an array, and your algorithm calls for an array (i.e. it requires no higher level list operations like insertion, removal, etc), it is best to stay clear of the List API.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code i am writing is for a priority queue for Dijkstra's Alogrithm. I think I'm kinda pinned into using arrayList.